# Install 'Documentation for Android SDK' via the command line

Tags: android

I'm looking for a way to automate the installation of the Android-SDK inside a docker-container, which works very well so far.
The only problem i don't seem to be able to solve is how to install the SDK-Documentation (e.g. 'Documentation for Android SDK' API-level 22) by using the the command-line options.

The command:

```
android list sdk --all --no-ui
```

lists all the available packages except the SDK-documentations for a specific API-level (the package 'Documentation for Android 'MNC' ...' is not what i'm looking for here).

Of course it's no problem to get it by using the SDK Manager but as stated i want to automate the installation process to keep changes for the docker-image as straight-forward as possible in the future.

Does anybody have a clue how to solve this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This problem will probably clear up in a couple of months, once we no longer have the M Developer Preview. My guess is that the command-line list only shows the latest, regardless of preview status, while the GUI shows the latest production and latest preview editions of the docs.

Comment: Well that could be a possibility. I guess time will tell. Thank you anyway.